# Use \cellcolor in \tabulary

Tags: tables, color, colortbl, tabulary

The `\cellcolor` command from package `colortbl` doesn't seem to have any effect in a `tabulary` environment, though it works in `tabular`. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\cellcolor{green}42
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{C}
\cellcolor{green}42
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

Is there something more to add, or a workaround?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Good minimal example!

Comment: such naive optimism to expect two packages written by the same person might actually work together:-)

Comment: (Nice test file: I'll look later)

Comment: This is fixed in tabulary 0.10 which has been submitted to ctan so should appear there in a day or so.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not sure if it is the right place, but it seems that there are 2 typos in documentation dated 2014/06/11: "as if the natuaral length was equal
to \tymax). This is initially set to twice the text width.." (natuAral and double dot)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke  thanks will fix (typos in my typing, shocking:-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tabulary` detects `colortbl` and inserts modified definitions for that case, but `\cellcolor` was "recently" added to `colortbl` in 2001: and `tabulary` wasn't updated to match.

> % \changes{v0.1j}{2001/02/13}{\cs{cellcolor} (Donald Arseneau)}

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter% needs to be after begin document

\patchcmd\@mkpream
{\let\CT@row@color\relax}
{\let\CT@row@color\relax\let\CT@cell@color\relax}
{\typeout{good}}
{\typeout{bad}}


\patchcmd\TY@classz
{\CT@row@color}
{\CT@row@color\CT@cell@color}
{\typeout{good}}
{\typeout{bad}}


\makeatletter

\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{red}}c}
a
\\
\cellcolor{green}42
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{>{\columncolor{red}}C}
a
\\
\cellcolor{green}42
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no idea what these lines mean, but it works. :) The first `\patchcmd` does not seem to be needed. What is it for?

Comment: @Neptilo actually it's probably not needed, I just looked at all the places where tabulary modified colortbl and made it do something for cellcolor whenever it did something for rowcolor:-) but actually you are unlikely to have cellcolor in the tabular preamble argument  so it probably isn't needed (does no harm though:-)

Comment: Interestingly, when adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, the error happens again, along with `Package tabulary Warning: No suitable columns`. What's happening?

Comment: @Neptilo wow I can confirm that, no idea: I'll look later, can't look now.

Comment: @Neptilo whatever it is it's unrelated to colortbl, as you get the same without it.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should open a new thread. But does anyone care about solving a warning?

Comment: @Neptilo I do:-)

Comment: New thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186170/usepackaget1fontenc-creates-warning-in-tabulary

Comment: That warning was unrelated (it was a side-effect of writing too small minimal examples). You actually have to add `\usepackage[french]{babel}` and the color doesn't show up.

Comment: @Neptilo with babel the patches don't apply (you should see `bad` from the typeout. I'm not sure why that happens but anyway if you get version 0.10 from ctan it works without the patch command

Comment: After waiting for ctan server for a long time to download the package, it works. :)