# \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} creates warning in \tabulary

Tags: tables, font-encodings, tabulary

An example will speak for itself:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}aa\end{tabular}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{C}aa\end{tabulary}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{C}bb\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

Here, a warning is raised by only the first `tabulary`. It says `Package tabulary Warning: No suitable columns`. Whether it happens depends on the content of the cell, but I could not really understand in what case.

Why does this warning appear? It seems like a bug in either `fontenc` or `tabulary` so it should be corrected.

**Note:** Even though it is *just a warning*, it alters the display of tables. See [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185762/use-cellcolor-in-tabulary). **Edit:** Actually not. The problem was unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the fact that the European Modern font have a slightly thinner em than Computer Modern.

If I load `tabulary` with the `debugshow` option, I get

```
Table
Target Width: 345.0pt
\tabcolsep: 6.0pt \arrayrulewidth: 0.4pt \doublerulesep: 2.0pt
\tymin: 10.0pt \tymax: 690.0pt
Col 1: Initial=22.00003pt         -12.0pt  Final=10.00003pt  > tymin

Line Width: 333.0pt, Natural Width: 10.00003pt, Ratio: 1
10.00003pt,  
Total:10.00003pt
```

for the first `tabulary` when `T1` is not loaded. Conversely, I get

```
Table
Target Width: 345.0pt
\tabcolsep: 6.0pt \arrayrulewidth: 0.4pt \doublerulesep: 2.0pt
\tymin: 10.0pt \tymax: 690.0pt
Col 1: Initial=21.99756pt         -12.0pt  Final=9.99756pt  < tymin

Package tabulary Warning: No suitable columns! on input line 10.


Line Width: 323.00244pt, Natural Width: 0.0pt, Ratio: 1
9.99756pt,  
Total:0.0pt
```

when `T1` is loaded.

If I add

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\tymin}{1em}}
```

to the document preamble, the diagnostic is

```
Table
Target Width: 345.0pt
\tabcolsep: 6.0pt \arrayrulewidth: 0.4pt \doublerulesep: 2.0pt
\tymin: 9.99756pt \tymax: 690.0pt
Col 1: Initial=21.99756pt         -12.0pt  Final=9.99756pt  > tymin

Line Width: 333.0pt, Natural Width: 9.99756pt, Ratio: 1
9.99756pt,  
Total:9.99756pt
```

that avoids the warning.

Comment: Wow, such knowledge! That removed the warning, thanks! (It doesn't seem to solve my previous problem though. Anyway.)

Comment: Yes I noticed that, possibly it's a feature or I could change the warning a bit, but hopefully except for MWE people are not using such narrow columns and asking TY to stretch them....

Comment: Oh, so that's because my column was too narrow. I agree it's not very common to use such narrow columns. It just happened as I was writing a minimal example document.

Comment: I am getting the same warning without using [fontenc] package.

Answer (score 4):

The column is narrower that `\tymin` which is `10pt` by default.  Set `\tymin` to a smaller value to avoid the warning:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tymin}{5pt}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{C}aa\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```